# How to setup source-folders for Django in intellij python-project? (Python-Plugin)

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, pycharm

i have a simple question, but i've not found any solution, neither in the docs nor the web...

How do i properly setup a source-files for Django-Project inside intellij-idea python-plugin?
I'm wondering if i should "mark" the folders containing my settings.py and my app-code "blue" so that intellij treats them as source-files?

[image: Project-Setup screenshot]

Intellij seems to behave differently in Package-View and in sourcecode-completion when importing things.

Which is the correct setting?

Comment: Marking the directories as `Sources` is not required. What specific problems do you have with completion?

Comment: for example: when i add these directories as sourcefolders, completion suggests the following line to import a Class from views.py into settings.py (stupid example; just to show imports from different packages):
`from views import ViewClass`
when disabling directories as sources it suggests the following (which looks correct for me, but i wasn't sure):
`from testApplication.views import ViewClass`

Comment: Configuring directories as Sources adds them to the `PYTHONPATH` explicitly.

Comment: That clarifies things!!!
Submit as answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking directories as `Sources` is not required. The effect is that the directory is added to `PYTHONPATH`.